# How to color text in log files in linux

Tags: linux, unix, logging, vim, colors

I want to add colors to the text in Log files. **For e.g. I would want lines that contain text 'ERROR', to be red colored**. So that when I view that file, these I should be able to easily find those lines with 'ERROR'. I tried looking for the answer to question but couldn't find anything helpful.
Thanks in advnace.

Comment: Try looking into [lnav](http://lnav.org/)

Comment: I suggest you don't add any color codes to the files themselves, but instead make sure the *viewer* can colorize the text. Many viewers and text editors include the ability to add custom highlighting.

Comment: How can I do this? I want to do it the way VIM defines color to code segment. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/318755/shell-customize-the-color-of-each-line-of-a-log-file-based-on-a-pattern) is something similar that you could check. Best,

Comment: Don't you know what `grep` is?

Comment: Great answer @Jean-BaptisteYunès

Answer (score 5):

Someprogrammerdude suggested to use ability of viewers to colorize output. It is called 'syntax highlighting' in vim ecosystem but not only there.

The simplest thing you can do in vim is:

```
:sy match my_error /.*ERROR.*/
:hi my_error ctermfg=red guifg=red
```

You can add these lines to your `.vimrc` or may better is to create a special syntax file for your log files where you can define more rules...

Answer (score 4):

> So that when I view that file, these I should be able to easily find those lines with 'ERROR'.

Coloring those lines would be one way but there's a much simpler and more idiomatic way:

```
$ grep ERROR /path/to/logfile | less
```

will show you every line containing `ERROR` from `/path/to/logfile` in `less`.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a utility for coloring log files called [TxtStyle](https://github.com/armandino/TxtStyle). It can color log files  based on regex patterns defined in a config file `~/.txts.conf`:

```
[Style="example"]
!red: regex("error")
green: regex("\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d")
# .. snip ..
```

To try it out, run (requires Python):

```
sudo pip install TxtStyle
wget -q https://raw.githubusercontent.com/armandino/TxtStyle/master/example.log
txts -n example example.log
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use ccze to color the files:

e.g.:

`docker logs -f <container> | ccze -m ansi`